# How to access the following firebase response

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

This is a firbase response I get. My question is how do I get access to the bills? It is an list of objects.

```json
{
    "MYxaNHnKxPfdPlmwVGj": {
        "bills": [
            {"name": "Leo", "price": 23423},
            {"name": "dds", "price": 3423},
            {"name": "sdasd12312", "price": 12321}
        ]
    },
    "MYxia564oxQm-iYUMkO": {
        "bills": [
            {"name": "Leo", "price": 200}
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a foreach over the map and you will be able to get the key and value of the map.

```
void main() {
  var usrMap = {
    "MYxaNHnKxPfdPlmwVGj": {
      "bills": [
        {"name": "Leo", "price": 23423},
        {"name": "dds", "price": 3423},
        {"name": "sdasd12312", "price": 12321}
      ]
    },
    "MYxia564oxQm-iYUMkO": {
      "bills": [
        {"name": "Leo", "price": 200}
      ]
    }
  };
  usrMap.forEach((k, v) {
    print('Key: $k');
    for(var bill in v['bills'] as List){
      print('Name: ${bill['name']}');
      print('Price: ${bill['price']}');
    }
  });
}
```